# Request method GET not supported error when serving static resources

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, static-resource

static resources not loaded at all and when it loaded this error appear i don't where the problem 
this is my code

> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <description>textSpring</description>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>my database</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/mysql</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Customer</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Customer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
              org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/Customer-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Customer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
             classpath:textSpring/configure/dao-context.xml
             classpath:textSpring/configure/service-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

> Customer-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans 
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="textSpring.controllerAll">
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="internalResourceViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>    
    </bean>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:resources location="/resource/" mapping="/src/*"></mvc:resources>
</beans>
```

> createOffer.jsp

```
.
.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/src/main.css" type="text/css"/>
.
.
```

[when i call createOffer.jsp form appear without style like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cOa9.jpg)

[and error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKFx6.jpg)

> if i call the static resource from url this is result

```
**http://localhost:8080/textSpring/src/main.css**

*HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
type Status report
message Request method 'GET' not supported
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.9*
```

> this is pox.xml file if it useful

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mmmez.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>textSpring</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>

        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <version>1</version>
</project>
```

Comment: update your project folder structure

Comment: I guess there is no src in deployed war (or jar) so all resources are not available because they added somewhere else folder

Comment: There seems to be a handler method (@RequestMapping) which also matches the same url as your static resurce that is picked first. Static resources handler has a lower precedence than the RequestMappingHandlerMapping. As for the resource location it must be in src/main/webapp/resource according to your config and not src/main/webapp/src as indicated above

Comment: @ekemchitsiga yes the problem in the (@RequestMapping) in my handler method i decorated it by this annotation @RequestMapping(name="anything", method=MethodRequest.POST)
when i removed  method=MethodRequest.POST from the annotation it worked when add it errors occurs

Comment: The handler is being considered the default if a match is not found. It will match for static resources as well as it considered before resource handling. Do you really need the default handler

Answer (score 0):

Based on the maven project structure please check whether the static resources are in the relevant folders of your project.

Your src/main.css should be present in in textSpring/src/main/webapp/src/main.css. Then you will be able to access it as http://localhost:8080/textSpring/src/main.css